# Threading runs my code even before the button is clicked

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def validator ():

    if desAddress.get()=='' and sourceAddress.get()=='' :
        messagebox.showwarning('Validator','Please enter the source address \n Enter destination address')
    elif sourceAddress.get()=='':
         messagebox.showwarning('Validator','Please enter the source address')
    elif desAddress.get()=='':
         messagebox.showwarning('Validator','Please enter the destination address')
    else:
      dataDir=sourceAddress.get()
      desDir=desAddress.get()
      readLable=pd.read_csv('D:/Users/Engr M2J/Downloads/Compressed/Dataset/HAM10000_metadata.csv')
      #print(readLable['dx'].value_counts())
      label=readLable['dx'].unique().tolist()
      #print (label)
      lable_images=[]

      for i in label:
           print(i)
           os.mkdir(desDir + str(i) + "/")
           sample=readLable[readLable["dx"]==i]['image_id']
           lable_images.extend(sample)
           progress=Progressbar(frameProgressBar,orient=HORIZONTAL,length=280,mode='determinate')
           progress.pack()
           progress['value'] +=40
           
           for id in lable_images:
                shutil.copyfile((dataDir + "/" + id + ".jpg"),(desDir + i + "/" + id + ".jpg"))
                lable_images=[]

               
arrange=Button(contentFrame, command=threading.Thread(target=validator), 
text="Classify",width=10,bg='gray',font= 
('tahoma',20,'bold'),activebackground='green',activeforeground='white').grid(row=3, 
column=1, pady=20)

desAddress.grid(row=1, column=1)
sourceAddress.grid(row=0,column=1)
mainFrame.pack()
contentFrame.pack()
frameProgressBar.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When running the validator function on my GUI, I noticed that the the app wasn't responding. I tried to use threading for it but the problem is that, on running the app, the thread runs my code for me without even pressing the button. the code was meant to run after pressing the button. What can I do as I am having been troubleshooting this for hours now

Comment: Did you mean: `command=lambda :threading.T...`?

Comment: Your posted code does not run `validator()` on program starts because `command=threading.Thread(target=validator)` will just assign the thread object to `command` option.  `validator()` will only be started when the `.start()` function is executed on the thread object.

Comment: sorry I mistakenly posted the old code. I inserted the start() and the code ran it itself instead of waiting for the click event. I want the code to run only when I have clicked the button

Comment: Then the first comment is the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did the magic